Problems trying to boot into usb
I have ubuntu installed on my main ssd and I want to replace it with windows 10. When I select any boot option except the main ssd with ubuntu installed, I get redirected to this. I have a gigabyte motherboard.

Ubuntu is not involved if it's being replaced.  You need to download a windows 10 ISO (if that's what you're trying to install) and write it to installation media as per Microsoft instructions, then boot it (as per your device procedures & its firmware settings) and then follow the windows 10 install steps. Why ask here? as this isn't a gigabyte or windows 10 support site?

That is exactly what I've done. I have no idea why ubuntu appears when I boot into my usb with the windows 10 installation.

Getting external media to boot is device specific; I have about 25 devices here & they have 9 different procedures to boot external media; some require specific keys to be pressed early in the boot process (problematic as the press has to be perfect; too early or too late & it'll boot what is already installed), others require me to enter firmware config & select external boot, one requires me to have device off & press and hold a specific key down for 4 secs then device turns on and asks if I want to boot external media.. It's not brand (gigabyte) specific but firmware specific

I enter the firmware config and boot into the usb but the ubuntu install thing just appears

If Ubuntu appears; you're not following the correct procedures for your model firmware OR your settings (ie. BIOS/uEFI settings)... which can be you're too early, too late with keystrokes etc...   Booting external media is device specific & we're not a hardware site.  The other possibility is your windows 10 media is invalid... but we're not a microsoft/windows support site either

Okay, I'll try again i guess. Sorry for being difficult.

This question is similar to: Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
